# Approach/are approaching?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> As you _______ the hotel, you will see a lake.
>
> A. Approach
>
> B. Are approaching
>
> C. Will approach
>
> D. Would approach

I honestly don't understand. The answer sheet says that since there's the word "as" here, the answer is "are approaching". Can you explain it a bit further? I just don't get it. "approach" seems equally correct to me. And I didn't eliminate the other 2 answers because although they seem less sensible to me, I still don't know why they would be incorrect. They just seem weird to me.

Comment: Would you please provide a link to the book, if it's possible? 

As a learner: "as" is a conjunction there which means "when something is happening". There is no strict rule that we should use "as" with present progressive or progressive aspect. The present progressive only conveys "during the period that you are approaching ( a short **ongoing event** ) you will see a lake".

Answer (score 1):

You grammar manual is blatantly wrong and should be shunned. The correct answer is:

> As you approach the hotel, you will see a lake.

The present simple here works similar to other clauses of indefinite time, e.g.

> When you enter the building you will see a picture on the left.

Comment: I think "are approaching" is correct, too. Isn't it?

Comment: @Cardinal, not in this context. You may [search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+you+approach+it+you+will+see%22) for it in GoogleBooks.

Comment: I don't think that kind of searching a whole sentence is a good way to judge about a sentence.

Comment: @Cardinal, the search I linked works well to show the very usage in which you are interested. It is not a full sentence.

Comment: Fine, does this have anything to do with that future clause? For instance, let's consider "As you are approaching the hotel, call me to guid you to my place." Is that wrong? I know it's very common in past tense, for example, : "Just as she was leaving the room, all the lights went off"

Comment: Yes, your first sentence is wrong, unless *as* is employed in the sense of *because*, *whereas*, *since*. Your second sentence, however, is correct, but I am hard pressed to explain the difference. It certainly is not due to tense. The original is a narrative of directions, somewhat similar to the [historic present](http://thefreedictionary.com/historic%20present). It assumes the viewpoint and timeframe of a traveler, retelling events as they happen. It is the sequence of events rather their continuity that is important, so the Present Simple is used.

Comment: Replacing *as* with *when* will more or less preserve the meaning: *When you approach the hotel you will see a lake.* Or you can rewrite it this way: *You will see a lake during your approach to the hotel.*

If you want to invert the emphasis and answer the question: *What were you doing when you saw the hotel?*, the progressive tense will be required: *I was approaching the hotel when I saw the lake.* You will also need it to stress the relation between two events in which one "envelops" the other, e.g.: *As I was approaching the beautiful stranger someone stepped on my loose shoestring.*